# Difference between 'will it' and 'would it'?

Tags: modal-verbs, spoken-english

Which is the correct sentence?

> **Will** it be solved? 
>   **Would** it be solved?

What are the differences between these two?

Comment: We can't tell which sentence works without context.  We don't know what you're trying to communicate, what the situation is, what you're responding to . . .

Comment: @snailboat:  The title question is perfectly proper.  The embedded question ("which is correct?") is a reasonable question for someone not understanding the nuances of English and assuming that only one would be correct.  If I could, I would vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which is the correct sentence?
>   Will it be solved?
>   Would it be solved?

Both sentences are correct English.  But they have different meanings.

> What are the differences between these two?

*Will it be solved?* asks the question *Is it solvable?*  Without additional context or qualification, it means *Will it *ever* be solved?*

*Would it be solved?* is bounded in time.  For instance, in the middle of hearing or reading a story, this question asks if some mystery is solved by the end of the story.

Answer (score 4):

> Will it be solved?

[Will](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will) is present tense so the solution could happen from the present to some time in the future.

> [Would](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would) it be solved?

Would is a past tense of will. The question is posed about a past where the problem hasn't been solved. It is ambiguous if the problem has currently been solved or not.